# Request is sent until timeout

Tags: php, arrays, file, function, request

I am working on a facebook app and I am trying to send some requests, but one particularly seems to create problems: under the NET panel of FireBug, I can see that the request is sent again and again until timeout.
What I am trying to do is: when the user clicks a button, a `function` from a PHP file should be called.
**save.php** (from where the request to call the function will be given)

```
<a id="done" href="savefunctions.php?runFunction=writeJSON">Done!</a>
```

The requests are properly sent to `http://localhost:8080/savefunctions.php?runFunction=writeJSON`  but don't ever seem to complete.

**savefunctions.php** (`$arrayForJSON is some array where data is saved and should be written to a JSON file.

```
function writeJSON()
{
$myfile="testson.json";
$fileout=fopen($myfile,'w') or die("Fatal: Can't open JSON file for writing");
global $arrayForJSON;
if(isset($arrayForJSON))
{fwrite($fileout,json_encode($arrayForJSON));
echo "done";
fclose($fileout);}
else echo "Error: could not write to JSON file";

}

//Global:

if(!empty($_GET["runFunction"])){
        if($_GET["runFunction"] == "writeJSON"){
            writeJSON();
        }
    }
```

The status of the request is "302 Found"

---

Edit: Looks like the array was empty and the request was (I still don't understand why) sent over and over until timeout. Now sometimes (looks like it does it randomly) the function runs, but doesn't do its job, other times it goes in the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP code, you have a condition for `runFunction` to be `writeJSON`.  You are passing `getAll`.  `writeJSON()` is never being called.

Try

```
<a id="done" href="savefunctions.php?runFunction=writeJSON">Done!</a>
```

Comment: Lol sorry for that, I pasted here from somewhere else. That getall works.
Actually my code is the way you wrote it. Sorry, I'm a bit tired. `href="savefunctions.php?runFunction=writeJSON"` does not work. I'll edit the question, thanks for pointing it out